# Is there a list of new programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, scripting-language

Does anybody know of a website that lists new scripting/programming languages (or old ones)? I'm not talking about new versions of existing languages, just new or old ones that most people haven't heard of. Even if they're not good languages...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best resources for listing languages is of course [99 bottles of beer](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/), featuring snippets for more than 1200 languages, including :

- brainfuck
- shakespear
- lolcode
- ada
- assembly

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia has a ["list of lists"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_programming_languages) of languages. [This one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) is particularly massive...

Any list of "new" languages is likely to get out of date pretty quickly. There will always be ones which are new *to you* though.

Answer (score 2):

http://roesler-ac.de/wolfram/hello.htm

Answer (score 2):

This page has a nice list in chronological order:

- [Timeline of programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List%5Fof%5Fprogramming%5Flanguages

Answer (score 1):

On the [Computer Languages History](http://www.levenez.com/lang/) page you can see how languages are related to each other.

Comment: I should print, frame and hang it in my office!

Answer (score 0):

Use google with the year

Example

(2015) Swift
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/

(2016) Ring programming language
http://ring-lang.net

(????) Not released yet!
the Jai programming language
https://github.com/BSVino/JaiPrimer/blob/master/JaiPrimer.md